# Selecting rows if there are NA values in specified columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
example <- data.frame(
  CID = c(091, 091, 091, 091,
          101, 101, 101),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1091, 1091,
            1101, 1101, 1101),
  PID_B = c(2091, NA, 2091, 2091,
            2101, NA, NA),
  text = c("eg1", "eg2", "eg3", "eg3", 
           "eg4","eg5", "eg6")
)
```

I want a dataframe with all the rows that have either NA in `PID_A` or `PID_B`. This is my code so far:

```
example_missing <- subset(example, subset=!(is.na(PID_A)|is.na(PID_B)))
```

However, it doesn't return what I want. Does anyone know how I can modify it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The problem is with your logical condition. You are subsetting the data where PID_A or PID_B is not NA (due to the 'not' operator (!) you are using).

Comment: There's also a convenience function `complete.cases`. You could apply it like this: `z <- !complete.cases(example[, c('PID_A', 'PID_B')]); example[z,]`

Answer (score 0):

to select only the rows which have NAs

```
df <- example[is.na(example$PID_A) | is.na(example$PID_B), ]
df
```

and to selct the rows which do not have NAs

```
df2 <- example[!(is.na(example$PID_A) | is.na(example$PID_B)), ]
df2
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-base R suggestion with `dplyr`

```
library(tidyerse)

example %>% 
  filter(if_any(contains("PID"), is.na))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
    CID PID_A PID_B text 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1    91  1091    NA eg2  
2   101  1101    NA eg5  
3   101  1101    NA eg6
```